# C realloc memory referenced by thread

Tags: c, multithreading, realloc

i have a C client structure that is realloc'd as the size increases from within the main loop, each client is a thread.

if i increase the size of the client structure, existing threads output random t_client->status data. i'm guessing realloc has modified the pointer to the client stucture memory and the clients are looking at the old pointer. can someone point me in the right direction how to solve?

```
//realloc client structure
client_array_len *= 2; //double
client = realloc(client, client_array_len * sizeof(struct client));

if (client == NULL){
    snprintf(log, sizeof(log), "[0] realloc error\n");
    log_info(log);
    exit(1);
}
```

```
//create thread
if (pthread_create(&thread_id, &thread_attr, t_client, &client[fd_new - 5]) < 0){
    snprintf(log, sizeof(log), "pthread_create error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    log_info(log);
}
```

```
//t_client
void *t_client(void *ptr_t_client)
{
    struct client *t_client;
    t_client = (struct client *)ptr_t_client;

    while (1)
    {
        sleep(2);
        snprintf(t_client->log, sizeof(t_client->log), " status:%d\n", t_client->status);
        log_client(t_client);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the thread gets a pointer to memory that is later driven through `realloc` by *anyone* without a protocol to ensure everyone that has the original pointer now has the new one, its a recipe for fail. You need a pointer to pointer and at least a mutex to ensure mutable actions taken against the pointed-to pointer are properly guarded. In your case, its worse because the thread isn't getting the base pointer; it's getting an offset from said-same.

Comment: Figure out where your critical segment is, and wrap it in a mutex.

Comment: @WhozCraig, understood, thanks.